Which translation of Psalm 113:9 is closest to the original?
We read in Psalm 113:9(RSV):

He gives the barren woman a home, making her the joyous mother of children.Praise the Lord!

We find various Versions presenting the above verse in   different phraseology eg:

He maketh the barren woman to keep house, and to be a joyful mother of children. Praise ye the Lord( KJV)
He makes the barren woman among her household a happy mother of joyful children.Hallelujah! (ISV)

My question is: which translation of Psalm 113:9 is closest  to the original ?

what sort of closest is wanted? This isn't limited to the three example versions, but presumably the closer-to-Hebrew Syriac Peshitta is excluded... and if the idea is to read the Psalm why does it matter which translation was closest?

Felix, I can see a significant difference when it refers to ' giving a home' and ' making the household happy' . Hence the Question.

Actually, the Hebrew of Ps 113:9 is tantalizingly terse.  Here is my VERY literal translation:

He gives barren home; mother of joyful children. Hallelujah [= "praise the LORD"]!

Now, while this makes some sense in Hebrew, it makes almost no sense in English; and thus words of interpretation must be added to render it anything other than nonsensical.  This fact accounts for the variety of ways the verse is translated.  However, we can be sure that some additions are defensible such as: adding "woman" after "barren".
After that, we have to make some difficult choices between:

He gives a barren woman a home, like a mother of joyful children.  Praise the LORD.
He gives a barren woman a home to make her like a mother of joyful children.  Praise the LORD.
etc.

All these are interpretive translations.  Thus, none of the OP's versions are strictly correct - all must interpret the text somewhat.

The OP has chosen a verse where the major translations are so scattered that one has to form some views about translation-philosophy.
Biblical Hermeneutics isn't supposed to assume semiotic positivism, but on this stack exchange it usually seems to in practice. That's contra Hans-Georg Gadamer, but Jacques Derrida went much further - arguing for untranslatability (e.g. Des Tours de Babel, 1985; Freud and the scene of Writing, 1967)
These translations of this verse might have given him quite a nice case study.

The first point I want to make is that all the major translations (except YLT) are in Imperial or Koine forms of English. There are still a sizeable cohort of people who were educated longer ago to make this their language-of-thought, but for the rest of us the major translations are only a stepping stone between the original text(s) and the dialects we think in.
If we have some fluency in the original language, there's still the hazard that our opinion of a translation is based on its closeness to our own language-of-thought... the author's language-of-thought being fundamentally unavailable.
A second thing that makes the OP's choice of Psalm 113:9 wonderful is that the Hebrew places its ideas in almost the same order as English would. So for once we can get away with 1:1 translation.
from https://biblehub.com/text/psalms/113-9.htm :-
He grants | the barren woman | a home | Like a mother | of children | [who is] Joyful | Praise | the Lord.
-> He grants the barren woman a home: a joyous mother of children. Praise the Lord.
The Hebrew doesn't have a comparative conjunction for "like" or "as" - these are supplied by the translations and might weaken the poetic metaphor, especially if it's referring to Sarah (or is that far-fetched and speculative?).
It turns out that's pretty close to RSV's or ESV's "He gives the barren woman a home, making her the joyous mother of children. Praise the Lord!"
But that's only really me describing my own mental dialect. ESV supply "making her" which I think goes too far the other way, and requires it to be about Sarah (or similar miracles). If we can preserve an allusion as an allusion that's "closer" translation, to my mind.

I'm conscious that:-
joyous is archaic for some dialects, but I prefer it to joyful because to me that would mean the mother was projecting joy outwards to her children. That's a reversal of purposive direction that isn't there in the imperially-imposed language of the target markets of the KJV and its many descendants.
barren is becoming a sensitive term since it's pejorative about people who were formerly birthing-people's reproductive biology. This might be why NIV read "childless" but that's again a dialect having a purposive difference. For me, the point about a "barren" woman isn't that she hasn't had children, but that she can't. Post-menopausal? Her family is complete? (as they're trained to say in British hospitals) It's not an easy one.
home is a loaded word in English because we converse it against the idea of a house. Hebrew doesn't really possess this converse, so we have an impossible dilemma whether to 'upgrade' a house to a home because it's in context of a woman being joyous about her children, or to preserve the idiom of the original language.
Hallelujah! is an example where the original word has become a loan-word. As a matter of good practice I prefer to re-render any loan-words as something else, because new ideas always get attached to them.

But those 4 things are only the tip of Derrida's iceberg. Every word needs a specific treatment for every reader, and this isn't translation so much as the sui-generis emergence of a text.
The OP in their comment may have mis-read ISV as "making the household happy" and there's a whole other set of strategies for making a translation easier-to-read or less prone to misreading.

Thanks,  Felix LXX for the well researched answer. The wise old people say: A house is made of stones, and a home --of  hearts ! Translation in my local language Malayalam presents the word as ' house' . If that is right, the verse would mean God giving a house or, a place to stay to the barren woman who would otherwise wander about as an outcast.

Perhaps, the Psalmist had in mind Hannah of  1 Samuel 1 who was prompted  to revolt by the ' adversary'  by making her believe that she was being discriminated against for the sole reason of having no children.
